# GPG decryption using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

There is a scenario where GPG Encryption is done using Python and Decryption should be done in Java. I have used Bouncy Castle API. I am getting below error. Any help on this is so much appreciated

Caused by: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Decryption failed - No secret key was found in the key ring matching the public key used to encrypt the file, aborting
at name.neuhalfen.projects.crypto.bouncycastle.openpgp.decrypting.DecryptionStreamFactory.nextDecryptedStream(DecryptionStreamFactory.java:152)

```
 final InMemoryKeyring keyring = KeyringConfigs
        .forGpgExportedKeys(KeyringConfigCallbacks.withPassword("testing"));
    keyring.addSecretKey(pvtKey.getBytes());
    keyring.addPublicKey(pubKey.getBytes());

    ByteArrayInputStream cipherTextStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encFilePath.getBytes());

    final InputStream decryptedInputStream = BouncyGPG.decryptAndVerifyStream()
        .withConfig(keyring)
        .andRequireSignatureFromAllKeys("recipent@test.com")
        .fromEncryptedInputStream(cipherTextStream);
```

Comment: Is 'testing'  the required passphrase when accessing your default key with gpg at the command line?

Comment: "testing" is the passpharse that is used in Python while encrypting.

Comment: Well, gpg normally requires a passphrase to *access* a private key. That is the default. If you've somehow done symmetric encryption *within* PKI, you'd therefore quite possibly need *two* passphrases - one for the private key access and another to supply the symmetric key (via passphrase)

Comment: Where we can find the default passpharse

Comment: When I say "default" I mean that *having* a passphrase for your private key is the default. You're asked for one on creation of the key pair afaicr

Comment: The same passphrase used in our Python code for both.

Comment: What happens with ```gpg -d thefilename```  at the command line?

Comment: I did not install GPG. I will install it and check